# Enzyme: shallow render inner react-redux components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, enzyme

I have simple react component, that use Card from antd:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { Card } from 'antd';

export class TBD extends Component {

  constructor() {
    super();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Card title={this.props.pathname}>
        TODO
      </Card>
    );
  }
}

export let select = (state) => {
  return state.route;
};

export default connect(select)(TBD);
```

Now I write some simple test and want to check, that my TBD component use Card

```
import React from 'react';
import {mount, shallow}  from 'enzyme';
import {Provider, connect}  from 'react-redux';
import {createMockStore}  from 'redux-test-utils';
import {expect} from 'chai';
import chai from 'chai';
import chaiEnzyme from 'chai-enzyme';
chai.use(chaiEnzyme());
import { Card } from 'antd';
import TBDConnected,  {TBD, select} from '../src/js/components/TBD';

describe('Fully Connected:', function () {
    it('show selected item text', function () {

      const expectedState = {route: {pathname: 'Menu1'}};
      const store = createMockStore(expectedState);
      const ConnectedComponent = connect(select)(TBDConnected);
      const component = shallow(<ConnectedComponent store={store} />).shallow().shallow();
      console.log(component.debug());
      expect(component.equals(<Card/>)).is.equal(true);
    });
  });
```

And it fail, because 3 shallow return me

```
<Component title="Menu1">
TODO
</Component>
```

But I'm expect

```
<Card title="Menu1">
TODO
</Card>
```

After one more render I get  pure html from rendering Card I'm not understand why it render it to Component instead Card and how I can get result what I want.

## Update

Example that simplifier my question. Next test fail:

```
describe('TBD', function () {
  it('Renders a Card', function () {
    const component = shallow(<TBD />);
    console.log(component.debug());
    expect(component.equals(<Card/>)).is.equal(true);
  });
});
```

Debug output in console:

```
<Component title={[undefined]}>
TODO
</Component>
```

But I expect:

```
<Card title={[undefined]}>
TODO
</Card>
```

Comment: `connect` is a Higher-Order Component and therefore wraps `Card` in a generic component.  I'd think that `shallow` would only render the first level (which would be the generic component).  This discussion might be useful: https://github.com/reactjs/redux/issues/1534

Comment: @DavinTryon, If I throw away all redux part (connect, store, etc.), and only render react component (it imported separately): `shallow(<TBD pathname='my title' />)`, then  i again get in result 
`<Component title="my title">
TODO
</Component>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem in Ant Delvelope components. Part of this components writed as simple anonymous functions, without extend React.Component, etc. In result Enzyme render it like `<Component />`, in browser it look like `<StatelessComponent />`.

Comment: Oh I see, we're using `className` and `find('.my-component')` to assert if a component renders, I'll debug my pure arrow function components to see if they behave as yours...

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to test the whole connected component.
I would test the *presentational pure component* first (as an unit test) and then you can test the *connector* in isolation.

I.E.

```
import React from 'react';
import {shallow}  from 'enzyme';
import {expect} from 'chai';
import chai from 'chai';
import chaiEnzyme from 'chai-enzyme';
chai.use(chaiEnzyme());
import { Card } from 'antd';
import {TBD} from '../src/js/components/TBD';

describe('TBD', function () {
  it('Renders a Card', function () {
    const component = shallow(<TBD />);
    expect(component.equals(<Card/>)).is.equal(true);
  });
  it('sets the right title', function () {
    const component = shallow(<TBD pathname="example" />);
    expect(component.prop('title')).is.equal("example");
  });
});
```

As you see, your pure component has to be tested as a pure function. You pass some props and expect some render.

Then when you test your connector, you can assert that it maps correctly the stateToProps and the dispatchToProps...

Comment: That will be perfect, but problem in test 'Renders a Card' - it fail. `console.log(component.debug());` for component in this test return `<Component title={[undefined]}>
TODO
</Component>`. And I doesn't understand why it render Card in it super class Component.

Comment: If you use a pure function instead a React.Component, it renders the <Card />?
`export const TBD = ({pathname}) => <Card title={pathname}>TODO</Card>`

Comment: No, still render as Component. And now I'm even more confused.

Comment: That's look like problem in antd components. I try same with own components and all work fine.